# What if I do sudo rm -rf /mnt/c/* in my WSL?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rm

Just for curiosity, what will happen after you run `sudo rm -rf /mnt/c/*` in WSL ([Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux))? Will it remove whole C drive in my computer? Will WSL keep working or not? If `sudo rm -rf /*`, will it remove the `/mnt` folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> what will happend after you run `sudo rm -rf /mnt/c/*` in wsl
>
> if `sudo rm -rf /*` will it remove `/mnt` folder

Both are similar scenarios.

No, it won't remove the whole drive, but it will still do substantial damage (as @DanielB [points out as well](https://superuser.com/a/1746342/1210833)).  See (and pity) [this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1354555/1165986), where the user accidentally did exactly what you are asking.

> I started getting all sorts of other errors from Windows
>
> Now everything is working weird even in Windows ... too much has been damaged.

While files in `C:\Windows` would be protected against deletion, those in `%userprofile%` (`C:\Users\<youruser>`) would not, including:

- Local and remote settings for most installed applications, including:

  - Your Start menu (`%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`)
  - Your browser settings, cookies, saved passwords, etc.
  - Ironically, your WSL distributions that were installed from the Store (`%localappdata%\Packages\<distro_package\`)
  - Your desktop.
  - Etc. etc. etc.
- Documents, Pictures, Downloads, Music, etc.
- Files stored on OneDrive, typically at `%userprofile%\OneDrive`.  Note that the files that are deleted here *would* go to the OneDrive Recycle Bin, unlike normal files deleted through WSL.

In short, it would be catastrophic.  Windows should still be bootable, but you would need to create a new user to recover.

However, if you were running WSL in UAC elevated (Admin) console, then the damage would be even worse.  It still wouldn't be able to remove in-use files, but it would wipe away enough of `/mnt/c/Windows`/`C:\Windows` to make it unbootable.

Answer (score 15):

Being root inside WSL does not make you an admin on Windows. So no, it will not remove the entirety of C:. It may however delete enough shared files and/or your stuff in your user profile to do quite some damage. You can still delete a lot there.

It could make it so you either can no longer log in or some of the software you installed fails.

Here’s what happens with protected files:

```
daniel@db-d-18:/mnt/c/Program Files/Firefox Developer Edition$ sudo rm install.log
rm: cannot remove 'install.log': Permission denied
```

---

You totally can destroy your WSL distribution this way of course.